# Simevents save and reload current state/status

Tags: matlab, simulink, simevents

I'm running some Simulink Simevents models.  Every time I need to start from certain initial condition, such as certain number of entities in different queues and certain resource/server states.  What I do currently is to let the model run for some time until the initial condition is researched, stop it, then test different parameters.  Is there a way to save and rerun from certain initial condition, so every time I can run from the same state?

Comment: I am utterly unfamiliar with simulink, but can't you simply feed your model different initial values? As in: you have some initial state from which the first run starts, so you can change those to the required values no?

Comment: For example, i want to know how long it takes to empty all the downstream buffers after I shut down the 2nd machine.  The initial conditions can be: 1st buffer 50% full, 2nd 75% full, 3rd 25% full and so on and all the machines are running in steady state.  The parameters I want to change are each machine's cycle time, MTBF and MTTR.  I need to run many times.  Right now I need to wait until each buffer gets to the right level.